# How to get Bitmap with actual size of it, in Bitmap variable irrespective of deivce I am using

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-drawable, android-bitmap, bitmapfactory

I have a jpg image of size 1080*1080 in my drawable folder, when I am storing it in a Bitmap variable the size of the bitmap is not showing as 1080*1080, it is showing based on the device I am using, I want to draw the actual image with size 1080*1080 on a canvas, any idea how to get the bitmap with actual size

```
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(activity.getResources(), R.drawable.template_image);
    int w = bitmap.getWidth();
    int h = bitmap.getHeight();
```

The variable **w and h** are not showing 1080*1080, it's different on different devices

Comment: Put it in `res/drawable-anydpi/`.

Comment: No it's not working, it's returning bitmap of very small size such as 7*7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put your image file in `drawable-nodpi` This folder tells android to avoid scaling your image file on any pixel density:

More Info [Medium Article](https://medium.com/@ramtintoosi/android-dp-fully-explained-46052e5b6aa)

If you need to only retrieve image size without showing inside image view:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
//Just Retreive info about the bitmap without loading inside memory to avoid OutOfMemory.
options.inJustDecodeBounds(true)
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(activity.getResources(), R.drawable.template_image, options);
int w = options.outWidth;
int h = options.outHeight;
```

Comment: @tushar I'm glad I could help you, please make the answer accepted (checkmark) so others can use this info if they had the same problem ;)